# Deleting a directory when clicked on a hyperlink

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I want to delete a `directory` when its clicked on a `hyperlink`.I tried like the below.But my page redirecting to `default(start) page` and the `directory` is not deleting.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Execute(s,Content,k,j);
}

private void Execute(string path,string cont,string sym,string space )
{
    foreach (var directory in new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories())
    {
        string f = directory.FullName;  
        f = Server.UrlPathEncode(f);

        Response.Write("<a href =''" + "onclick='Delete(" + f + ")'> DELETE </a>");

        Execute(directory.FullName,cont1,sym1,space1);
    }
}

private void Delete(string path)
{
    DirectoryInfo DirDel = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    DirDel.Delete();
}
```

Can you tell me the problem in this code?

Answer (score 1):

You're rendering clientside code, expecting it to call serverside code. This will never work, clientside always happens on their machine, not on your server.

What you want is to use a [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) control, e.g.:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>LinkButton Example</title>
    <script language="C#" runat="server">

    protected void LinkButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        // Code to delete directory
    }

    </script>    
</head>
<body>

   <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <h3>LinkButton Example</h3>

       <asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
           Text="Click Me" 
           Font-Names="Verdana" 
           Font-Size="14pt" 
           OnClick="LinkButton_Click" 
           runat="server"/>

       <br />

       <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server" />

    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How can I write it in .cs file?

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590: The part in the `<script language="C#" runat="server"></script>` tag would go in your seperate .cs file, as a method of your page class. You'd still need the aspx page. See http://asp.net-tutorials.com/basics/code-behind/

Comment: I know that but I want to create the linkbutton dynamically where it is required and how can i pass path to the LinkButton_Click.

Comment: @ILLUMINATI7590: See http://shahed-kazi.blogspot.com/2009/07/dynamically-add-button-control-to.html for an example. re. passing the path to `linkbutton_click`, when you create the control store the directory in the Tag property. When `linkbutton_click` is called cast the sender object to a `linkbutton` and access it's `tag` property.

Comment: It's rather better to use code-behind in 2011, then don't, really

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear from your question, where you have that folder, if it is on the client side, then i think it is not possible.

If it is on the server side you could use a link button instead of an anchor tag to run the code behind function

If you cant use the link button for some reason you could use JavaScript ajax calls to call the code behind function.
Here is a [code project article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CallCodeBehindByJS.aspx), that may help you

Answer (score 1):

The **general problem** is that you create client-side URLs, but method to call is server-side. So you need to create server-side URLs, and handle postback click:

```
string path = @"d:\Temp";

protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    string dir = this.Request["dir"];
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dir)) // write links
    {
        foreach (var di in new DirectoryInfo(path).EnumerateDirectories())
        {
            var link = new HyperLink()
            {
                Text = di.Name,
                NavigateUrl = String.Format("?dir={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(di.Name))
            };
            this.Controls.Add(link);
        }
    }
    else // process link click
    {
        dir = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(dir);
        path = Path.Combine(path, dir);
        Directory.Delete(path);

        Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx"); // page's name to refresh content
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my code can you check it and tell me how to do it? I'm not able to understand your approach.

Comment: @ILLUMINATI: on load you need to check, was any clicked (query string contains directory name), or was not

Answer (score 0):

You should use a LinkButton to get the same look as the , but you need your code to be execute on server side as the PostBack for your LinkButton.

The code you have here will make a call to a client-side script.