# Deleting a directory when clicked on a hyperlink with JAvascript.ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, hyperlink, onclick

This isn't working:

```
 Response.Write("<a href=view.aspx?type="+Content+"onclick=\"Delete('"+f+"')\"> DELETE </a>");


  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function Delete(path) {
        path1 = unescape(path);
        var myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var myFolder = myObject.GetFolder(path1);

        myFolder.Delete();

        alert("Welcome");
    }
 </script>
```

But this worked.

```
  Response.Write("<a href=view.aspx?type="+Content+"onclick=\"Delete()\"> DELETE </a>");

  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function Delete() {

        alert("Welcome");
    }
 </script>
```

I tried with onclick for `Delete()` to get just `ALERT` it worked well.
But it isn't working when add the parameters.Can you help me please.Trying for this from long time please.

Comment: Have you looked at the final HTML? Have you tried to debug it on the browser side using a tool like Firebug?

Comment: How about this `Delete('"+f+"')` , notice the single quotes

Comment: Add `alert(path);` as the first line of your `Delete` function and let us know what you get. And/or use View Source within your browser to see what your server-side code is actually outputting.

Comment: I added the alert but actually nothing happening and page is refreshed to the first page.

Comment: In page source `<a href=view.aspx?type=notes onclick="Delete('C:\Users\naresh\Documents\Visual%20Studio%202010\WebSites\ContentMan\users\user01\notes\BIOLOGY\ENGLISH\HELLO')"> DELETE </a>`

Comment: just do not do it! the ActiveX way works only in IE on Windows.

Comment: Leave the ActiveX I couldn't alert the path also by commenting everything else.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting a directory when clicked on a hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421926/deleting-a-directory-when-clicked-on-a-hyperlink)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, \u is escpae code for a hex digit. So better re-format it.

Second, href=view.aspx?type=notes is not a valid html syntax too. Double quotes please.

Third, please put some code to check if your javascript variables (myObject,myFolder) are valid (not null) before invoke any method against them.