# Deleting a directory using Javascript ActiveXObject

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, activex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting a directory when clicked on a hyperlink with JAvascript.ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436192/deleting-a-directory-when-clicked-on-a-hyperlink-with-javascript-asp-net-c)

```
 string Del="Delete('"+f2+"')";
 Response.Write("<div align=" + "center" + "><td><a href="+"javascript:location.reload(true)"+
" onclick="+Del+" > DELETE </a></td></div><br />");


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function Delete(path) {

        path1 = unescape(path);
        alert(path1);
        var myObject = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

        myObject.DeleteFolder(path1,true);
        alert("Welcome");
  }
  </script>
```

I'm deleting a directory like this.But for this I had to enable `Run ActiveX` and some other.
Can't I do it in any other way where there is no need of these enabling.And I came to know this works only in `IE` so how can I do it in other browsers?

Comment: didn't you ask the same question 2 days ago?

Comment: Yes and sorry that time actually I'm not able to delete it now I can but having doubts abt other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this with Javascript at all, you can do it server side where you have the ASP.NET engine and the .NET framework in your help, you can make the call with ajax so there is no page refresh if you are using web forms and it looks like if it was done all client side, transparent to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it in other browsers because only IE supports ActiveXObjects. Other option may be using Flash or Silverlight or Java Applets, but I am not sure browsers will allow you to delete a directory.